# Styles in Adobe Flash Builder Mobile Project

Tags: css, apache-flex, styles, flash-builder, flex-skins

What is the CSS equivalent for HTML, in Adobe Flash Builder. I understand that Adobe Flash Builder Mobile projects use Flex and Action script to code. However I want to create a style for all of my buttons on the page. How do I do this in an Adobe Flash Builder Application. Typically in CSS I would create a CSS style sheet, and place it in the directory of my website then just reference that style sheet into each of the pages or html files.

How do implement this same approach with adobe flash builder ?

Comment: You, basically, do the same thing in a Flex project as you would in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

See [Using Styles in Flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ffe.html)

and

[Using Local Style Definitions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e8b.html)